# Css and html alignment issue with divs and images in a div

Tags: html, css

Im building my first responsive type website, So far doing the index page. Im having an issue when that i cannot align the footer divs together. i have three divs spread out and the last div on the right has social 4 icons. but im unable to get these to align with the other two divs texts. Ive tried a number of different things to fix it in the css and flex though id rather stick to css right now on this site.
Here is the site on test host to see the actual icons in the footer.
https://hireahottub2.netlify.com/

i feel the problem may lie in my code somewhere but i cannot see it for the life of me.

align-items: center
display:inline block is in the parent

```
<html>
<footer>
      <div id="footerwrap">
        <div class="fdiv1">
          <h5>Hire A Hot Tub, Goole, DN14 6QT</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="fdiv2">
          <h5>Web Design by DM DESIGN</h5>
        </div>
        <div class="fdiv3">
          <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hireahottub2000" target="_blank"
            ><img src="./img/fb2.png"
          /></a>
          <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hireahottub2000" target="_blank"
            ><img src="./img/insta2.png"
          /></a>
          <a href="https://twitter.com/HireahottubUK" target="_blank"
            ><img src="./img/twitter2.png"
          /></a>
          <a href="mailto:hireahottub2000@hotmail.com" target="_blank"
            ><img src="./img/email2.png"
          /></a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </footer>
</html>

/* FOOTER CSS */

footer{
  padding: 5px;
  margin-top:;
  color:#ffffff;
  background-color: #354243;
  text-align: center;
  font: bold;
  border-top: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

#footerwrap{
width: 80%;
text-align: center;
}

.fdiv1{
float: center;
display: inline-block;
width: 20%;
}

.fdiv2{
float: left;
width: 20%;
}

.fdiv3{
float: right;
width: 20%;  
min-width: 75px;
}

.fdiv3 img{
  width: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Still trying to figure this out, but one quick comment... there is no such thing as "float: center", only left and right.

Comment: Another problem is that you have `display: flex` on the `<footer>` element, but then just one `<div>` that's *immediately* inside the footer. It's only the one direct child of the `<footer>` that will be acted upon by the flexbox layout, not the child elements of that one inner `<div>`, which are only grandchildren to the footer.

Comment: ok thanks lol i took that out. do you see what i mean on the live site the icons are stuck to the top of the footer and i cannot line them up. Thanks for looking at this for me. I appreciate the help.

Comment: i dont think there is a display flex on the css code. i tried to do it without.  didnt want to use flex on this one as i only started doing this on monday. i learnt a bit about flex yesterday and was just seeing if it worked. maybe the deploy was an old one i updated the deploy on netlify.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendations are:

1. Get rid of all of the `float` stuff.
2. Get rid of the `width: 20%` stuff on the footer items. (Maybe bring it back after you see the results of the rest of this.)
3. Get rid of the single inner `<div>` that's a child to the `<footer>` element (I guess you said you already did that somewhere else, just not on the current demo website).
4. Use the flex `justify-content` (`space-between`) and `align-items` (`center`) CSS attributes on your `<footer>` to spread your footer items out in the proper fashion.

Follow up...

I tried the above, ended up keeping the `width: 20%`, and got this as a result:

[image: screenshot]

I guess you might want to switch the order of those first two footer items around, but that's not something I could do easily just playing with CSS attributes in my web console.

Comment: Thanks copyied my page and tried this out on the copy. I didnt want to use flex box on this site just yet. wanted to create one without. But i appriciate the help on that. It ligned the items up perfectly but used the full width of the screen probably because there were no constraints on its container. Ive dabbled with flex on my previous iteration. not very good mind. https://hireahottub.netlify.com/ but ive only been doing this a week so i apprecate the help.

Answer (score 0):

For your issue specifically, I'm seeing that your divs fdiv1 and fdiv2 only align in the center because of browser-set margins on the heading tags within them. Furthermore, they have zero concept of the height of any other div, because they are floated (removed from document flow). To fix this, you will need to set them all an equal height. Then vertical-align will actually work.

```
h5 {
    margin: 0;
}

.fdiv1, .fdiv2, .fdiv3 {
    height: 50px;
}

a {
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

It may be beneficial for you to learn [Flexbox](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/). It makes these types of tasks easy, but it's not supported in older browsers.

Comment: hi thanks for that. that got them all to line up perfectly even when minimised with my 4 stack of social logos. However they were all aligned to the top of the footer itself. im sure i can find that issue out though. It does look good though. I have been dabbling with flex box on another site. Before this one. https://hireahottub.netlify.com/ Im not great. ive only been doing this since monday lol.

Answer (score 0):

Hello this is a solution if you want to stick with only CSS ( without flex ) :

```
footer{
    padding: 5px;
    position: relative;
    margin-top:;
    color:#ffffff;
    background-color: #354243;
    text-align: center;
    font: bold;
    border-top: #e8491d 3px solid;
}

.fdiv3{
   width: 20%;  
   min-width: 75px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   right: 0;
   transform: translate(0,-50%);
}

.fdiv2{    
   width: 20%;
   width: 20%;
   min-width: 75px;
   position: absolute;
   top: 50%;
   left: 0;
   transform: translate(0,-50%);
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Use a [css grid layout](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) to achieve this.

```css
footer {
  padding: 5px;
  color: #ffffff;
  background-color: #354243;
  text-align: center;
  border-top: #e8491d 3px solid;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
  align-items: center;
}

footer div img {
  width: 30px;
}
```

```html
<footer>
  <div class="fdiv1">
    <h5>Hire A Hot Tub, Goole, DN14 6QT</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="fdiv2">
    <h5>Web Design by DM DESIGN</h5>
  </div>
  <div class="fdiv3">
    <a href="https://www.facebook.com/hireahottub2000" target="_blank"><img src="./img/fb2.png" /></a>
    <a href="https://www.instagram.com/hireahottub2000" target="_blank"><img src="./img/insta2.png" /></a>
    <a href="https://twitter.com/HireahottubUK" target="_blank"><img src="./img/twitter2.png" /></a>
    <a href="mailto:hireahottub2000@hotmail.com" target="_blank"><img src="./img/email2.png" /></a>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Thanks. that also gets them to line up perfectly and keeps the logos in a straight line  however. but another great solution i can look at.